# How to Use Ajax in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I want send selected drop down menu value to **controller** by ajax

**panel_controller.rb**

```
class PanelController < ApplicationController

      def insert
         @city_ids = params[:city]
      end
end
```

**panel.js.erb**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#f_city_id').change(function() {
        var city_js_id = this.value
        $.ajax({
            url: '/panel/insert',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {"city": city_js_id},
            success: function (data,status)
            {
                alert(this.url);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

**routes.rb**

```
get '/panel/insert' => 'panel#insert'
```

**views/panel/insert.html.erb**

```
<%= @city_ids %>
```

> but **@city_ids** dont respond value after chenge drop down menu

Comment: `data: {"city": city_js_id}` should be `data: {city: city_js_id}`

Comment: @Emu I change to {city: city_js_id} but dont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to respond back from your `insert` method.

Try doing this

```
class PanelController < ApplicationController
  def insert
    @city_ids = params[:city]
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render partial: 'insert.html.erb' }
    end
  end
end
```

Create a partial file with the new content `_insert.html.erb`

```
<%= @city_ids %>
```

In you panel.js.erb try catching the response and append it in your DOM wherever necessary. Your updated value will be on the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#f_city_id').change(function() {
    var city_js_id = this.value
    $.ajax({
        url: '/panel/insert',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {"city": city_js_id},
        success: function (res){
            $("#somediv").html(res);
            //You will get the partial's content with the new data and you'll only need to append it to your page.
        }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: I try this But dont work ==> **Error {Template is missing}**

Comment: You can give the full path. Lets say your partial resides inside `views/panel/_inser.html.erb`. Do `render partial: 'panel/insert.html.erb'`

Comment: Look at the error, it must be giving you the path where it didn't find. You'll be able to fix it. :)

Comment: i want show in my view not in partial and i fix path but There are error

Comment: Yes. The partial will be rendered with the updated information from the server so new information will show on your view. What error do you get?